# Is there a way to have a seperate featurecontext file for different features

Tags: behat

I am new to behat and noticed that every .feature file I create gets added to the FeatureContext.php when I run --dry-run --append-snippets
on the command line

But its going to get messy if I have tons of tests in the FeatureContext.php file

Is there a way where I can have a different "FeatureContext" class set up for different .feature files?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Easy way!

```
class FeatureContext extends MinkContext implements KernelAwareInterface
{
}

class MessageContext extends FeatureContext
{
}

class MailContext extends FeatureContext
{
}
```

Or you can do this way:

```
class FeatureContext extends MinkContext implements KernelAwareInterface
{
    public function __construct(array $parameters)
    {
        $this->useContext('message_context', new MessageContext());
        $this->useContext('mail_context', new MailContext());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Will behat automatically look into both classes or do I have to tell it what class to search?

Comment: When you write a new gherkin step definition in your new Context file, it will automatically pick it up. e.g. step definition: `Then I say hello` MailContext: `/** @Then /^I say hello$/ */public function iSayHello() { return 'Hello'; }`

Comment: Okay got it. Thanks a lot!